# What begins with letter T and ends with letter T, use after death?

Tags: riddle, word

What begins with letter T and ends with letter T, use after death?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, Tots :) Unfortunately this riddle is very broad, as a case can be made for many different answers, all arguably equally valid (see the answers and comments already given below). I've voted to close the question because of this. A little friendly advice: When creating riddles, try to think about ways you can help people find the specific answer you have in mind - if lots of answers are valid, you need to add another line, hint or clue that helps rule those other ones out... Keep trying, and keep puzzling! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You use a **teapot** only after killing the leaves.

Comment: Do we know what makes this answer correct and not taxidermist or trout, etc?

Comment: Actually not sure if this was the intention but if I read this as instead "ends with T" then I see... yes, very clever!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think I've ever posted a serious answer to a question with this many plausible solutions, so maybe it's time that I, at
last, will:

> TESTAMENT

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer might be

> TAXIDERMIST

which is used for

> Preserving an animal's body via mounting or stuffing for the purpose of display after death.